# VS Code "Python pip is not found in current environment" error

Tags: visual-studio-code

To program esp32, I want to load the esperssif idf for vs code. I ran into a problem at the last stage. VS Code wants from me:
"Add your ESP-IDF virtual environment python executable absolute path. Example: C:.espressif\python_env\idf4.0_py3.8_env\bin\python.exe". But there is no bin folder in the specified location within the espressif folder. "python.exe" is located in another directory. When I paste that directory, it gives a warning like "Python pip is not found in current environment".

how should i solve this problem?

Comment: The example path is invalid and not absolute. It's a relative path appended to a mount (drive letter).

Comment: what you say is true. However, there is no bin folder inside the espressif folder directory on my computer. Python.exe does not exist at all.

Comment: Even if vscode shows me a sample directory, won't I still find the espressif folder and search for it?